# how to change the contents inside <a> tag into image field using css?

Tags: javascript, css

```
<a href="/category/sarres" rel="nofollow" class="facetapi-zero-results facetapi-active">(-)</a>
```

I need to replace the (-) by an image
How can I achieve this using css in drupal?

Comment: This is simple javascript. Please make an attempt.

Comment: Can I achieve it using css?

Comment: No, you cannot do this with CSS.

Answer (score 2):

I'll assume that by "replace" you mean to add an image inside an `<a>` tag through css only.

Yes, it is possible. You can use [**Css Pseudo Elements**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-elements). Something like:

```
a:before {
    content: url('img.jpg');
}
```

[**Sample JsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/v1rq8aLq/)

Or, if you really want to "replace" it, you can use a simple Javascript approach:

```
var element = document.getElementById('anchor_id'); //Or whichever DOM select method you want.
element.innerHTML = "<img src='img.jpg' />";
```

And, if you still wants something more robust, you can use `document.createElement` to create the image element, and then `.appendChild()` to place it inside the anchor.

There are endless solutions... :)

Comment: Hmm.. this is really clever, it would be a full value answer if you also included a js way of doing it

Comment: set `color:white;` or whatever the background color is to hide the link text "(-)".

Comment: This answer works but assumes that all anchors will have the `(-)` in them. Going off the class name "zero results" I assume that this is only there when an image isn't already provided. Prob just trying to put in a placeholder. I added an answer that might be more appropriate, Let me know @19greg96

Answer (score 0):

Here is a more robust solution to supplement @LcSalazer solution

```
var a = document.getElementsByClassName('facetapi-zero-results');

var arr = Array.prototype.slice.call( a )

arr.forEach(function (item) {
  if ( item.innerHTML == "(-)" ) {
    item.innerHTML = "<img src='http://placehold.it/300x300'>"
  }
})
```

Answer (score -1):

To me it seems like you're trying to do this:

```
<a href="/category/sarres" rel="nofollow" class="facetapi-zero-results facetapi-active"><img src = "yourimage.png"/></a>
```

This wraps the image in a link.

Comment: I'm only guessing: because op asked how to do this at runtime. ie. manipulate the DOM with js